Transformation of a 2D space to "concentric circle" space.
I am wondering, is it possible to define a transformation of a 2D Cartesian space that:

it transforms any line parallel to the X-axis into a circle with some radius $R + y$, where $y$ is the ordinate of this line in Cartesian space;
Any vertical line ($x = const$ in Cartesian space) transformed into a radial line;
A linear function (i.e., $y=kx+b$) would be transformed into a spiral.

Don't know where to start, maybe there is some literature on the subject?
Thanks

Do you know of "polar coordinates"?

Ah, ok, didn't think it would be this easy :)
